Impute NA values in a column based on another column with a different scale



Person
Score1
Score2




Alice
5.6
3.2


Bob
9.3
8.7


Charlie
7.2
NA


Dave
-4
NA


John
NA
10


Henry
11
13


Jane
3
8



I have a table like this. Most people have two scores (Score1 and Score2). These scores are on different scales.
I want to impute missing NA values in one column using their score in the other column to determine what their score would have been if they taken the test. For example, for Charlie I want to use his Score1 of 7.2 and determine what his score would be for Score2 had he taken the test.
How would I do this? I am assuming to start I would need to make both columns be on the same scale. I wouldn't want to use MinMaxScaler for increased variability.
I think this works:
feature = df[['Score1']]
feature2 = df[['Score2']]
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(feature.values)
df[['Score1']] = scaler.fit_transform(feature.values)
df[['Score2']] = scaler.fit_transform(feature2.values)


One way of doing this is to use a regression model and then predict the values. Note that you need to first replace the nan with the mean and then scale the data. If you don't you won't be able to use a regression model:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = {
    'Person': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave', 'John', 'Henry', 'Jane'],
    'Score1': [5.6, 9.3, 7.2, -4, np.nan, 11, 3],
    'Score2': [3.2, 8.7, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 13, 8]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df['Score1_filled'] = df['Score1'].fillna(df['Score1'].mean())
df['Score2_filled'] = df['Score2'].fillna(df['Score2'].mean())

scaler = StandardScaler()
df[['Score1_scaled', 'Score2_scaled']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Score1_filled', 'Score2_filled']])


train_data = df.dropna(subset=['Score1', 'Score2'])

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(train_data[['Score1_scaled']], train_data['Score2_scaled'])

missing_score2 = df.loc[df['Score2'].isnull(), 'Score1_scaled']
predicted_score2_scaled = model.predict(missing_score2.values.reshape(-1, 1))
df.loc[df['Score2'].isnull(), 'Score2_scaled'] = predicted_score2_scaled

df[['Score1', 'Score2']] = scaler.inverse_transform(df[['Score1_scaled', 'Score2_scaled']])

print(df[['Person', 'Score1', 'Score2']])

Which returns:
    Person  Score1     Score2
0    Alice    5.60   3.200000
1      Bob    9.30   8.700000
2  Charlie    7.20   8.206991
3     Dave   -4.00   0.139177
4     John    5.35  10.000000
5    Henry   11.00  13.000000
6     Jane    3.00   8.000000


Maybe worth noting that the two scores are not well-correlated (0.6) so any such answers have a significant potential error not reflected in the precision presented.
